# Pandas: group by equal range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is an example of my data frame:

```
df_lst = [
  {"wordcount": 100, "Stats": 198765, "id": 34},
     {"wordcount": 99, "Stats": 98765, "id": 35},
     {"wordcount": 200, "Stats": 18765, "id": 36},
     {"wordcount": 250, "Stats": 788765, "id": 37},
     {"wordcount": 345, "Stats": 12765, "id": 38},
     {"wordcount": 456, "Stats": 238765, "id": 39},
     {"wordcount": 478, "Stats": 1934, "id": 40},
     {"wordcount": 890, "Stats": 19845, "id": 41},
     {"wordcount": 812, "Stats": 1987, "id": 42}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_lst)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.head()
```

DF:

```
    Stats   wordcount
id      
34  198765  100
35  98765   99
36  18765   200
37  788765  250
38  12765   345
```

I'd like to calculate the average `Stats` for each range of `wordcount` with a step of 100 so the new data frame looks something like this:

```
    Average wordcount
    194567  100
    23456   200
    2378    300
    ...
```

Where 100 means from 0-100 etc. I started writing multiple conditions but have a feeling there is a more efficient way of achieving this. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [92]: bins = np.arange(0, df['wordcount'].max().round(-2) + 100, 100)

In [94]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df['wordcount'], bins=bins, labels=bins[1:]))['Stats'].mean()
Out[94]:
wordcount
100    148765.0
200     18765.0
300    788765.0
400     12765.0
500    120349.5
600         NaN
700         NaN
800         NaN
900     10916.0
Name: Stats, dtype: float64
```

Comment: OH my god same to same. You got this.

Comment: @Bharath, sorry about that :)

Comment: I was usually fast with pd.cut but not this time.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted - Thanks!

Comment: @aviss adding a new method :-) hope it helps ~ :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 100.0)) * 100
df['roundup']=df.wordcount.apply(roundup)
df.groupby('roundup').Stats.mean()
Out[824]: 
roundup
100    148765.0
200     18765.0
300    788765.0
400     12765.0
500    120349.5
900     10916.0
Name: Stats, dtype: float64
```