# How can I dynamically create bins in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following np array:

```
[['ID1', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID1', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID2', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID2', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID2', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID3', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID3', 700.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID3', 1200, 'Product 2'],
['ID3', 850, 'Product 1']]
```

The '2nd column' ($ amount) is what I care about.  I want to build a histogram of product 1 and product 2, but I want the bins to be sized by 100.  The actual data set I'm using has 75K rows and values that range from $1 to $200000.  I want to automatically create these 'buckets' for the values and then build a histogram.

I thought it would be easy to find info on this using either pandas or numpy but I am either a newb and not able to understand other 'similar' solutions, or am just not finding what I'm looking for.  Seems like it should be straight forward.

Comment: Each row is that one string or three seperate columns or values with a space as a delimeter?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079717/pandas-group-by-equal-range) is very similar to that what you are looking for...

Comment: @ScottBoston I'm really not sure.  It starts as a dataframe and I convert it as such 'dataset = dataset.values'; print(dataset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a histogram by turning your data into a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
a = [['ID1', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID1', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID1', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID2', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID2', 922.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID2', 1001, 'Product 2'],
['ID3', 800, 'Product 1'],
['ID3', 700.63, 'Product 1'],
['ID3', 1200, 'Product 2'],
['ID3', 850, 'Product 1']]
q=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['id','price','product'])
q.hist(column='price',bins=100)
```

[image]

You can specify the number of bins you want with the `bins` parameter:

```
 q.hist(column='price', bins=100)
```

[image]

If you want to group it by product use the `by` parameter:

```
 q.hist(column='price', bins=100,by='product')
```

[image]

Comment: what does column=1 mean?  Is that referencing the index of 1?

Comment: I modified the code to give the price column a real name

Comment: Awesome, one more thing, how could you separate this out and have two histograms based on each product?